is there a way to get Android device IMEI 1 & IMEI 2?
i tried many cmd of adb to get IMEI 2 of android device but failed. is there any way to get the IMEI 2 of and android device via adb or c# lib.
i tried various commands from stackoverflow to retrieve the IMEI 2 but was not successful ki

Yes there is, Search for AT+Command for retrieve IMEI for connected device.

could you please provide me with a sample or some link to find the AT command?  thank you.

@RahulArya It is depending on what type device you are connecting with, search in it is documentations for this device.
